# Conflicting results for $\int\frac{|x+1|}{x}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, absolute-value, piecewise-continuity

I've encountered an obstacle while trying to solve the following integral:
$$\int{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+1}}{x}dx}$$
First thing we shall do is see that under the square root is actually $(x+1)^2$. When I cancelled the square root I got the following integral:
$$\int{\frac{|x+1|}{x}\,\mathrm dx}$$
After that I've separated the problem into two cases:
$1.$ Case:
$$\int{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+1}}{x}dx}=-x-\ln|x|+C,\space x<-1$$
$2.$ Case:
$$\int{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+1}}{x}dx}=x+\ln|x|+C,\space x>-1, x\neq{0}$$

But this apparently isn't the correct solution and the only solution is:
$$\int{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+1}}{x}dx}=x+\ln|x|+C,\space x\neq{0}$$
Is this really the case, and if yes, then why?

Comment: The most general solution is $-x-\ln(-x)+A$ for $x<-1$, $x+\ln(-x)+B$ for $-1<x<0$, $\,x+\ln x+C$ for $x>0$. See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2218109).

Comment: @J.G. That was what I was writing in my answer ;-; I got this from Dr. Trefor Bazett though so we have different sources ;)

Comment: @J.G. so there are in fact three cases? Though for school purposes (seems like we were thaught wrong), my solution would be correct, the one with two cases, right?

Comment: It's one solution with three parameters. @KamalSaleh I'd be interested to see Bazett's discussion if it's online.

Comment: @J.G sorry for late edit, but can you reply to my question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

\begin{align}
\int{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+1}}{x}\,\mathrm dx}={}&\int\frac{|x+1|}{x}\,\mathrm dx\\
={}&\int\operatorname{sgn}(x+1)\left(1+\frac1x\right)\,\mathrm dx\\
={}&\begin{cases}
-x-\ln(-x)-2+C_1, &x<-1;\\
x+\ln(-x)+C_1, &-1\le x<0;\\
x+\ln(x)+C_2, &x>0
\end{cases}
\end{align}

1. This integrand is disconnected at just $0,$ so its indefinite integral requires exactly two [independent parameters](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4631163/21813) to capture its complete set of antiderivatives.
2. The `-2` adjustment in the first case (alternatively: a `+2` adjustment in the second case) is necessary! Without it, the left piece of each antiderivative (i.e., for each $(C_1,C_2)$ couple) is discontinuous, and therefore not differentiable, at $-1$ (a non-differentiable antiderivative is of course a contradiction). It is easy to neglect this adjustment and write<sup>†</sup> \begin{align}
   \int_{-2}^{-0.5}\frac{|x+1|}{x}\,\mathrm dx
   ={}&\int_{-2}^{-0.5}\operatorname{sgn}(x+1)\left(1+\frac1x\right)\,\mathrm dx\\
   \color{red}={}&\Big[\operatorname{sgn}(x+1)\left(x+\ln(-x)\right)\Big]_{-2}^{-0.5}\quad\quad\Large\color{red}✗\\
   ={}&-2.5,\end{align} which is incorrect, because in fact $$\int_{-2}^{-0.5}\frac{|x+1|}{x}\,\mathrm dx=-0.5.$$

[A visual proof](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/8rbmhnbq4v):

[image]

<sup>†</sup>When computing the integral on $[a,b]$ of a continuous piecewise function, using the FTC piece-wise is equivalent to determining its indefinite integral then using the FTC once (at $a$ and $b$).

Comment: Since the red curve is continuous in $-1$ (bounded suffice though) there should exists a value of $C_1$ for which the anti-derivative in continuous in $-1$, this is not the case for your result, but $-x-\ln(-x)-C_1$ for $C_1=1$ works.

Comment: @zwim I don't understand your suggestion (the part after "but"), but I've just edited the answer to incorporate your fantastic observation (the part before "but"). Thanks so much for pointing out the subtlety!

Comment: I think the more obvious way to see that $\operatorname{sgn}(x+1)(x+\ln|x|)+C$ is incorrect is to note it gives $$\lim_{\epsilon \to 0^+} \int_{-1-\epsilon}^{-1+\epsilon} \frac{|x+1|}{x} \mathrm{d}x = -2$$ but with the integrand bounded on $x \in [-2,-1/2]$, this limit must be $0$.

Comment: In fact $\displaystyle\sigma(x)\int f(t)dt$ is ultimately $\displaystyle\sigma(x)\int_{x_0}^x f(t)dt=\sigma(x)\Big(F(x)+C\Big)$ with $C=-F(x_0)$ and the $C$ is affected by the sign function $\sigma$. But you put it outside.

Comment: @zwim Thanks for your 2nd comment (reminding that when making the abovementioned edit, I'd neglected to bring that $\sgn$ function in Line 2 back into the indefinite integral); I've just made the correction.

Answer (score 2):

The piece-wise integrations may be combined as follows
\begin{align}
&\int{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x+1}}{x}\,dx}\\
=&\ \frac{|x+1|}{x+1} \int{\frac{x+1}{x}\,dx}= \frac{|x+1|}{x+1}(x+\ln |x|)+C\\
\end{align}
where the domain-dependence of the constant is understood.

Comment: Neat trick (+1)

Comment: @ryang - Already pointed out in the answer is its piece-wise representation; you incorrectly applied it to $(-2,-0.5)$

Comment: "domain-dependence of the constant" doesn't describe exactly how it changes, though, in particular the difference of $2$ near $x=-1$.

Comment: @ryang - As already pointed out, one should apply the result piece-wise, e.g. $\int_{-2}^{-1} + \int_{-1}^{-0.5}$. Doing so does not rely on any tacitness

Comment: @Quanto Okay, that's fair. *declutters away the above*.  $\quad$ A nitpick: while $-1$ lies in the integrand's domain, none of your solution antiderivatives are defined at this point.